# Programmatic custom cell memory leak issue

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, xcode4.5, autorelease

I have recently switched to "Programming Without XIB's" and facing an issue with Custom TableView cells. Previously when using XIB, I used the following code which worked perfectly,

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
AttachmentCustomCell *cell=(AttachmentCustomCell*)[self.attachmenttableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell==nil){
    NSArray* objects= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AttachmentCustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    AttachmentCustomCell *acell = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
    cell = acell;
}
```

but now I am using the following,which gives me a memory leak,

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
ConditionReportCustomCell *cell = (ConditionReportCustomCell*)[self.inventoryTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell==nil){
    cell = [[ConditionReportCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
}
return cell;
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I know I cant use autorelease as it results in crashing of the application.

Comment: Using ARC in your Pro ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I am not using ARC

Answer (score 2):

if you are NOT using ARC just add an autorelease:

```
cell = [[[ConditionReportCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease] ;
```

Comment: I dont want to use autorelease. Using autorelease crashes my application. Any other solution?

Comment: @shantanu... it crashes? then you have some other problem somewhere, the right way is to use an autorelease, here... are you releasing the cell elsewhere?

Comment: "any other solution?"... your code leak, the only way is to release, if it crashes, it means you are probably releasing in other part of you code...